# Auto fill password using Text Input React Native

Tags: react-native

Based on the docs, if we set textContentType to username and password, the keyboard should have an option to autofill. But somehow It is not working for me.

```
              <TextInput
                textContentType='username'
                style={{ width: 300, height: 50, borderWidth: 1 }}
                value={this.state.currentEmail}
                onChangeText={this.handleChangeTextEmail}
              />
              <TextInput
                textContentType='password'
                value={this.state.currentPassword}
                textContentType="password"
                style={{ width: 300, height: 50, borderWidth: 1, marginTop: 10 }}
                onChangeText={this.handleChangeTextPassword}
                secureTextEntry
              />
```

Is there anyone facing the same problem or is there anyway to fix this?

EDIT: 

 I'm using Iphone X (real device) Iphone 11(Simulator) both ios version is 11+

Comment: what kind of device and OS version (iOS/Android) and RN do you use?

Comment: According to the docs, you need to [add `autoComplete={true}` for Android](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/textinput#autocomplete-android). For IOS, it should suffice to only [add the textContentType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/textinput#textcontenttype-ios).

Comment: @kosiakMD I'm using RN 0.63 and the device I edited the post

Comment: does that feature work with others Apps?

m.b it's turned off?
will update my asnwer

`iCloud Keychain is used: Settings → Apple ID → iCloud → Keychain → toggle "On" the iCloud Keychain.`

Comment: its already toggle on, and i just init new react native project and try the text input but does not work

Answer (score 1):

1. What kind of device faces this issue?
2. what kind of OS iOS/Android version?
3. I think to propose autofill form the password chain it should contain `password` and **`username`** instead of `emailAddress`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/textinput#textcontenttype-ios

> For iOS 11+ you can set `textContentType` to `username` or `password` to
> enable autofill of login details from the device keychain.

if `v11+`

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.username}
    textContentType="username"
/>
<TextInput
    value={this.state.password}
    secureTextEntry={true}
    textContentType="password"
/>
```

if `v12+`

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.username}
    textContentType="username"
/>
<TextInput
    value={this.state.password}
    secureTextEntry={true}
    textContentType={"password" | "newPassword"} // newPassword if suggest & save into cahins
/>
```

UPD: 07.10.2021

4. ensure that Keychain autofill is turned **ON**

> iCloud Keychain is used: Settings → Apple ID → iCloud → Keychain →
> toggle "On" the iCloud Keychain.

as here https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/textinput#passwordrules-ios

Comment: Hello @kosiak, thanks for answering. 
But I've try username and password before switch to content address but not work.
The device version I've just updated in the post

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by following the way

1. Add autocorrect true in the email field and give the margin for iOS
2. Add extra dummy text input between email and password for only the iOS platform with the wrapping of parent View pointer none for avoiding focus

final code

```
  <TextInput
        autoCompleteType="email"
        autoCorrect={true}
        clearTextOnFocus={false}
        containerStyle={{marginTop: 5, marginBottom: isIos() ? -20 : 0}}
        keyboard="email-address"
        textContentType="emailAddress"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={(value): void => onInputChange('username', value)}
      />

      {isIos() ? (
        <View pointerEvents="none">
          <TextInput
            focusable={false}
            style={{color: '#00000000'}}
            onChangeText={(value): void => onInputChange('username', value)}
          />
        </View>
      ) : null}

      <TextInput
        autoCorrect={false}
        clearTextOnFocus={false}
        containerStyle={{marginTop: 5}}
        keyboard={isIos() ? 'ascii-capable' : 'default'}
        secureTextEntry={true}
        value={password}
        onChangeText={(value): void => onInputChange('password', value)}
      />
```